# fullpage.js - when using anchored links, are the pages loaded at once or on demand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) and I have to set up external links for each of the pages/tabs to be navigated to.

Now my question is, are the pages loaded when navigated to, or at page load, which I want to avoid, I only want to load the pages when I navigate to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin doesn't do it by itself. You won't find any documentation about it.

If you want to load things on demand you could do it using ajax ([$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), for example) by using a fullpage callback such as [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index).

You could something like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
        $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( data );
            alert( "Load was performed." );
        });
    }

});
```

If you only need to dynamically load background images, then I would recommend you to use CSS styles for it. 
You can read more about it in [this answer in fullpage.js forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/46#issuecomment-26509996).